# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery

Tags: java, android

So I have this strange bug. I'm using simple cursor adapter for my suggestion searchView and a database. I don't need content provider so I'm not using it. The thing is that I don't have a command that closes my DB or cursor anywhere in my code, but I'm still getting this error. 
The error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT _id as _id, title as suggest_text_1, subTitle as suggest_text_2, imgUrl as suggest_icon_1, searchID as suggest_intent_data_id FROM suggestions WHERE (title like ? ) ORDER BY title asc  LIMIT 10
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:152)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:124)
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:214)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getItemId(CursorAdapter.java:225)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.rememberSyncState(AdapterView.java:1199)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:815)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6117)
        at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
        at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:347)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:326)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:315)
        at android.support.v4.widget.CursorFilter.publishResults(CursorFilter.java:68)
        at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

My suggestion method:

```
  public synchronized Cursor getSuggestions(String[] selectionArgs) {
    String selection = FIELD_title + " like ? ";

    if (selectionArgs != null) {
        if (!selectionArgs[0].isEmpty()) {
            selectionArgs[0].replaceAll("'", "");
            selectionArgs[0] = "%" + selectionArgs[0] + "%";
        } else {
            selection = null;
            selectionArgs = null;
        }
    }

    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(mAliasMap);
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE2_NAME);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mSearchDBOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = null;
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        c = queryBuilder.query(db,
                new String[]{"_ID",
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
                        SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID},
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null,
                null,
                FIELD_title + " asc ", "10"
        );
    }
    return c;
}
```

Now I would like to note that my DB is instantiated only once, I'm not leaking it and I have only one activity. What I noticed is that this error is more likely to happen when there is a race condition. My onQueryTextChange listener:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            query = newText;
            query = query.replaceAll("[\\s%\"^#<>{}\\\\|`]", "%20");

            if (query.length() > 1) {
            // same problem here
               fireOtherMethod();
            } else {
                    String[] selArgs = {query};
                    searchDB.cleanAutoCompleteRecords();
                    Log.e("c.isClosed()", String.valueOf(searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs).isClosed()));
                     searchAdapter.changeCursor(searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs));
            }

            return true;
        }
```

The log reports that the cursor is always opened, my DB also. The error happens when I try to change the cursor:

> searchAdapter.changeCursor(searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs));

So if I just fire:

> searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs)

There is no problem, no crash.

I can't catch this error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated!

**Update:**
I have tried doing this:

```
Cursor c = searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs); 
Cursor oldC = searchAdapter.getCursor(); 
if (oldC != null && !oldC.isClosed()) 
  oldC.close(); 
if (!c.isClosed()) 
  searchAdapter.changeCursor(c); 
else searchAdapter.changeCursor(null);
```

But the result is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Seems the problem was in the changeCursor method:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29

What I think is happening when I clear the text from the searchView with backspace the event is called so many times and changeCursor method also. This closes the old cursor and maybe there is a chance that the old cursor at this moment is trying to make a query from the DB. So I override the changeCursor method:

```
        searchAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.suggestionrow, null, from, to, 0) {
        @Override
        public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            super.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    };
```

And now everything is good.

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling changeCursor you are closing the existing cursor.

> public void changeCursor (Cursor cursor)
>
> Added in API level 1 Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If
>   there is an existing cursor it will be closed.

You could try closing the current cursor and then creating a new cursor, rather than passing the new cursor through the changeCursor(new cursor), when it has not been created yet.

Always good to check if current cursor exists or is closed, if those errors show up when attempting this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: Ok, does this mean if I change the cursor with a new cursor which has the same results as the old one, the program will crash?

Comment: But in my method getSuggestions I'm always making a new cursor and returning it. Also I have two different methods which make SQL selection from two different tables. That's why I'm changing the cursor.

Comment: Well I tried this:
                Cursor c = searchDB.getSuggestions(selArgs);
                Cursor oldC = searchAdapter.getCursor();
                if (oldC != null && !oldC.isClosed())
                    oldC.close();
                if (!c.isClosed())
                    searchAdapter.changeCursor(c);
                else searchAdapter.changeCursor(null);
                
                Still no success.